# How to remove fields in the python set that contains a pattern from values exist in other set

Tags: python, python-3.x

By following code, I am trying to remove **Chinese**, and **German** from languages which is a set, but it doesn't work. Can anybody please help me with this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

languages = {'English', 'French', 'Persian', 'German', 'Chinese'}
junk = {'ine', 'erm', 'glo'}
languages -= junk

languages
{'English', 'French', 'Persian', 'German', 'Chinese'}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you change this one line `junk = {'German', 'Chinese'}`, the code will actually do what you want. The set minus operation will remove all elements in the second set from the first set if present. Right now, you're removing "ine", "erm" and "glo" from `languages`, which obviously will not get rid of German or Chinese

Comment: @LukasThaler but how can I remove fields that are contains any field in the junk? Actually I want to remove Chiness and German because they container  "ine" and "erm" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

This should be more efficient if the number of patterns increases, and it obviously supports RegEx, which makes it far more powerful.

```py
import re
from typing import List, Pattern, Set

languages: Set[str] = {'English', 'French', 'Persian', 'German', 'Chinese'}

junk: List[str] = ['ine', 'erm', 'glo']
junk_re: Pattern[str] = re.compile('|'.join(junk))

clean_set: Set[str] = {item for item in languages if not junk_re.search(item)}
```

---

#### Explanations

The words which come after the `:` in variable definitions are [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). No need to worry, it's entirely unrelated to this particular solution. These particular annotations might also be incorrect, since I am new to the subject myself.

[`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) combines multiple strings with a separator or delimiter. For example: `', '.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])` -> `'a, b, c'`.

In our case, the result is `'erm|glo|ine'`. The `'|'` character is actually the regex [alternation operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), which means that our pattern will match `'erm'` OR `'glo'` OR `'ine'`. I really like the website https://regex101.com for understanding and writing RegEx.

[`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) creates a regular expression object from our string, which we can then use to perform all the standard regex operations. Compiling our regex wasn't necessary, I just find it makes the code slightly easier to read/understand.

[`Pattern.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) (or `re.search()` if the pattern hasn't been compiled) searches through the string for a match: If it does find a match, it immediately returns a match object. If doesn't find any matches, it returns `None`.

Here are some examples to illustrate some of what we've covered so far:

```py
junk: List[str] = ['ine', 'erm', 'glo']
junk_re_str: str = 'erm|glo|ine'
junk_re: Pattern[str] = re.compile('|'.join(junk))

print(junk_re.search('Chinese'))  # <re.Match object; span=(2, 5), match='ine'>
print(junk_re.search('German'))  # <re.Match object; span=(1, 4), match='erm'>
print(junk_re.search('French'))  # None

print(re.search(junk_re_str, 'Chinese'))  # <re.Match object; span=(2, 5), match='ine'>
print(re.search(junk_re_str, 'German'))  # <re.Match object; span=(1, 4), match='erm'>
print(re.search(junk_re_str, 'French'))  # None
```

`{item for item in languages if not junk_re.search(item)}` is a set comprehension, the equivalent of list comprehensions for, you guessed it, sets. In case you're not familiar, a list comprehension is special syntax to create a list. They are often used in place of simple for loops which repeatedly append to a list.

Here are some examples of list and set comprehensions, along with their equivalent for loops:

```py
# Lists
animal_names: List[str] = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'giraffe']

list_1: List[str] = [f'a large {curr}' for curr in animal_names]
print(list_1)  # ['a large dog', 'a large cat', 'a large mouse', 'a large giraffe']

list_2: List[str] = []
for curr in animal_names:
    list_2.append(f'a large {curr}')
print(list_2)  # ['a large dog', 'a large cat', 'a large mouse', 'a large giraffe']

# Sets
nums_list: List[int] = [1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5]

set_1: Set[int] = {2 * curr for curr in nums_list}
print(set_1)  # {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}

set_2: Set[int] = set()
for curr in nums_list:
    set_2.add(2 * curr)
print(set_2)  # {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}
```

The `if not junk_re.search(item)` part of the list comprehension might seem odd, since we saw earlier that `search()` will return either `None` or a match object. When evaluated as booleans. however, None is considered false and the match object is considered true.

---

Let me know if you have any further questions :)

Comment: @AnotherDude I forgot to ask if you have any questions. I didn’t explain my solution at all.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what happen in the these two lines? 

junk_re = re.compile('|'.join(junk))
clean_set = {item for item in languages if not junk_re.search(item)}

Thank you so much

Comment: @AnotherDude How familiar are you with RegEx? I’ll add the explanations as an edit to my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately in a very basic level.

Comment: Cécil Thank you so much. This is the most clear explanation ever

Comment: @AnotherDude If it answers your question well, do feel free to accept it :) (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `all()` builtin method:

```
languages = {'English', 'French', 'Persian', 'German', 'Chinese'}
junk = {'ine', 'erm', 'glo'}

print({lang for lang in languages if all(j not in lang for j in junk)})
```

Prints:

```
{'English', 'French', 'Persian'}
```

Comment: It’s cleaner to write `j not in lang` than `not j in lang`.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes, I think you're right. Edited my answer.